# Can't make it take more targets

Tags: php, xml

I'm no PHP Guru i normally work with C#

But i got to edit some old php files. but its making a fuss.
my 2 arrays $line1 & $line2 keeps getting filled with the same data. 
Feel free to look at the XML to [LINK](http://freenats.multimed.dk/api.php?mode=xml&apikey=uig534&query%5B0%5D=test&param%5B0%5D=7&query%5B1%5D=test&param%5B1%5D=8&query%5B2%5D=test&param%5B2%5D=9&query%5B3%5D=test&param%5B3%5D=51&query%5B4%5D=test&param%5B4%5D=38&query%5B5%5D=test&param%5B5%5D=43&query%5B6%5D=test&param%5B6%5D=41&query%5B7%5D=test&param%5B7%5D=55)

My goal is to make it so :

Line 1; Ping has testid="7"

Line 1; http has testid="9"

Line 2; Ping has testid="8"

Line 2; http has testid="51"

```
define("TESTLINE_1", "TDC");
define("TESTLINE_2", "GC");

$line1 = Array();
$line2 = Array();

$xml = WP_CONTENT_DIR.'http://freenats.multimed.dk/api.php?mode=xml&apikey=uig534&query%5b0%5d=test&param%5b0%5d=7&query%5b1%5d=test&param%5b1%5d=8&query%5b2%5d=test&param%5b2%5d=9&query%5b3%5d=test&param%5b3%5d=51&query%5b4%5d=test&param%5b4%5d=38&query%5b5%5d=test&param%5b5%5d=43&query%5b6%5d=test&param%5b6%5d=41&query%5b7%5d=test&param%5b7%5d=55';
$feed = simplexml_load_file($xml);

foreach ($feed->test as $test){
if(strpos($test->testname, TESTLINE_1)){
    $line1 = AddTestinfoToArray($line1, $test);
}
else if(strpos($test->testname, TESTLINE_2)){
    $line2 = AddTestinfoToArray($line2, $test);
   }
}
```

Comment: try adding `break`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this hope this will be helpful. You were missing `[]`, As there are no `testname` which contains `Arrownet` so `$line2` will be empty array.

```
<?php

ini_set("display_errors", 1);
define("TESTLINE_1", "TDC");
define("TESTLINE_2", "GC");

$line1 = Array();
$line2 = Array();

$xml = 'http://freenats.multimed.dk/api.php?mode=xml&apikey=uig534&query%5b0%5d=test&param%5b0%5d=7&query%5b1%5d=test&param%5b1%5d=8&query%5b2%5d=test&param%5b2%5d=9&query%5b3%5d=test&param%5b3%5d=51&query%5b4%5d=test&param%5b4%5d=38&query%5b5%5d=test&param%5b5%5d=43&query%5b6%5d=test&param%5b6%5d=41&query%5b7%5d=test&param%5b7%5d=55';
$feed = simplexml_load_file($xml);


foreach ($feed->test as $test)
{
    if (strpos($test->testname, TESTLINE_1))
    {
        $line1[] = (string)$test->testname;//added this line
    } else if (strpos($test->testname, TESTLINE_2))
    {
        $line2[] = (string)$test->testname;//added this line
    }
}
print_r($line1);
print_r($line2);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. the one called TDC can you tell me what field it hits in the XML file. It will be a great help. cause i changed Arrownet with GC and both fields ended up blank.

Comment: Do you want to remove those which contains `TDC` and `Arrownet`?

Comment: Just the one with Arrownet and replace it with GC

Comment: There is no field `testname` which contains `Arrownet`., If i am not getting you point can you update your expected result in your post?

Comment: @LokeLindhardt I have updated my post for `GC` as well you can check it

Comment: Of Course, its those 2 (GC & TDC) I'm interested in when i leave in TDC and leave the other blank i get the TDC result in both fields (Line1 and 2)  and when i put something in test line 2 both fields turn up blank.
define("TESTLINE_1", "TDC");
define("TESTLINE_2", "GC");

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144927/discussion-between-sahil-gulati-and-loke-lindhardt).

Comment: Sadly no, but i think its the array it self http://www.dmdd.dk/services/driftstatus/ if you look up to the far left you can see the 2 arrays shown as text.

Answer (score 1):

Try this I hope It will respond to your needs

```
 ini_set("display_errors", 1);

    $line1 = Array();
    $line2 = Array();

    $xml = 'http://freenats.multimed.dk/api.php?mode=xml&apikey=uig534&query%5b0%5d=test&param%5b0%5d=7&query%5b1%5d=test&param%5b1%5d=8&query%5b2%5d=test&param%5b2%5d=9&query%5b3%5d=test&param%5b3%5d=51&query%5b4%5d=test&param%5b4%5d=38&query%5b5%5d=test&param%5b5%5d=43&query%5b6%5d=test&param%5b6%5d=41&query%5b7%5d=test&param%5b7%5d=55';
    $feed = simplexml_load_file($xml);

    foreach ($feed->test as $test)
    {
        if (strpos($test->testname, "TDC"))
        {
            if(strpos($test->testname, 'pingtest')){
                $line1[] = 'Ping has testid='.(string)$test->testid;//added this line
            }else{
                $line1[] = 'Http has testid='.(string)$test->testid;//added this line
            }
        } else if (strpos($test->testname, "GC"))
        {
            if(strpos($test->testname, 'pingtest')){
                $line2[] = 'Ping has testid='.(string)$test->testid;//added this line
            }else{
                $line2[] = 'Http has testid='.(string)$test->testid;//added this line
            }
        }
    }
    print_r($line1);
    print_r($line2);
```